# Set user privileges in MySQL for any host

Tags: mysql, excel

I´m trying to connect the MySQL database with Excel table trough ODBC connector. I´m on localhost using newest XAMPP version.

In phpmyadmin I need to set root user privileges to any host % but after submitting I´m still getting error.

[image]

By older XAMPP version was everything ok and I had available user with % privileges. After update it is problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure about working with XAMPP, but you can try giving execute rights to any user using this command

grant execute  ON db.*  TO 'userX'@'%';

You can also check for the available grant on user

**show grants for 'userX'@'%';**

Comment: i need privileges for all host names.

Comment: select Execute_priv from  mysql.user where user='userX' and host='%';      check this

Answer (score 0):

Execute this statement in the console:

```
grant <required privileges> to 'root'@'localhost' identified by '<yourpass>'; flush privileges;
```

I am not sure about the syntax displayed in your error message.

Comment: this code is not working. What I have to use instead of yourpass?

Comment: Let me explain, suppose I want to have a select privilege to a user called 'monitor', then it will be like this: grant SELECT to 'monitor'@'localhost' identified by 'monitor123';